# How to consume WinRT component inside Win32 dll project?

Tags: dll, windows-runtime, c++-winrt, winrt-component

Using [Registration-free WinRT](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/04/30/enhancing-non-packaged-desktop-apps-using-windows-runtime-components/) it is possible to load WinRT components inside Win32 application.

What's the process to load WinRT component from inside Win32 dll? I tried the steps mentioned as part of Win32, but winmd files are not generating the corresponding header files.

Main usage scenario is dll can be loaded any application, like electron node addon or c# app etc.,
Without any changes to application, dll by itself should be able to consume WinRT component!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Following is the solution:**
Was able to fix this in weird manner i.e. not a standard way to solve this.

Our use case was to use FFmpegInteropX inside win32 dll, so that we can use ffmpeg as a source reader and use the underlying hardware decode support. Mechanism is discussed detailly in the following link:

https://github.com/ffmpeginteropx/FFmpegInteropX/discussions/275#discussioncomment-3091100

Following changes were done to use WinRT component inside a Win32 dll:

1. Copied the WinRT generated files from the application to Win32 dll project
2. Before invoking any of the api from the generated runtime class, did LoadLibrary of the specific WinRT component into the dll
3. Now the make the necessary WinRT component call as it was done in standard win32 application

All modules were working as expected.

Above solution was copied from:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/924996/how-to-consume-winrt-component-inside-win32-dll-pr.html

It's not a straight forward solution, also not sure if MS has any plans to add support for WinRT component inside dll project, if such support comes up then this may not be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a reference to the WinMD file in the vcxproj and then installed the C++/WinRT NuGet package? This should make it generate the corresponding header files that your DLL project can then consume.

Comment: Yes, referenced WinMD file using the props file where with IsWinMDFile set to true. Also double confirmed the path of WinMD file.

Comment: Then added reference to Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT nuget package.

But header files for the corresponding WinMD file is not getting generated!